# rmarkdown - plot intermediate results of function

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am using rmarkdown to create a html document. I have a simple code chunk with a function. Inside the function are two plots generated.

Now, when I run the code, both plots are shown below the code chunk. However, I would like to show the plots right below its plot() function. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? 
Thanks, Philipp

```
a <- 1:20
b <- 21:40

test_this <- function(a, b){

  dd <- cos(a)
  plot(dd) # => plot 1

  ee <- sin(b)
  plot(ee) # => plot 2

}

test_this(a,b)
```

My html page looks like this!!!!

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I would like it to be like this:

```
a <- 1:20
b <- 21:40

test_this <- function(a, b){

  dd <- cos(a)
  plot(dd) # => plot 1
```

[image]

```
  ee <- sin(b)
  plot(ee) # => plot 2
```

[image]

```
test_this(a,b)
```

Comment: Why not just split it into two different chunks?

Comment: [Author of knitr and maintainer of rmarkdown here] This is not possible (well, nothing is impossible, but the price would be too high for this case).

Comment: @YihuiXie, thank you.